# Hide first radio and label with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a group of radio choices that are generated from an external server. I need to hide any radios and labels with label "None".

Here is how the HTML looks:

```
<div class="productAttributeList top-emx" style="">
<div class="productAttributeRow productAttributeConfigurablePickListSet">
<div class="productAttributeLabel">
    <label for="be91177516ac23bfe33ba180741486ee">
        <span class="name">Delivery Options:</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="productAttributeValue">
<div class="productOptionViewRadio">
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[139]"
            value="" checked="checked" />
            <span class="name">(None)</span>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="validation"  name="attribute[139]"
            value="86" />
            <span class="name">Standard Shipping</span>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="validation"  name="attribute[139]"
            value="89" />
            <span class="name">2 Day Express Shipping</span>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="validation"  name="attribute[139]"
            value="90" />
            <span class="name">3 Day Express Shipping</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>  
</div>
```

Tried this but I'm thinking I'm way off as it does nothing.

```
<script>  
    $('.productOptionViewRadio' li:first).hide();  
</script>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `li` that contains the label of `(None)` isn't always the first in the `.productOptionViewRadio` list, you won't be able to hide it using the selector you have put together (ignoring the slight typo in the selector anyway).

You can use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, which will match any or all of the `<label>(None)</label>` elements:

```
$(".productOptionViewRadio span.name:contains('(None)')").parents('li').remove();
```

Here's a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mu2uX/2/) - notice how it removes elements that are further down the list, too (unlike the other answers, which will only ever remove the first `li`, regardless of its `<span>`'s content).

Comment: BenM, Thanks so much, this is brilliant! Appreciate the attention to the possiblity None appearing in a different order. Cheers! Susan

Comment: Glad to help Susan, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. Your selector has error

```
 $('.productOptionViewRadio li:first').hide();
```

Additionally, you should wrap your code in

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
     $('.productOptionViewRadio li:first').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was initially misunderstood your requirement while seeing the unedited question, Any way you can select the spans with class `.name` and then you can `filter` those collection by using the condition `its text equals to '(none)'`, then just hide it

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('span.name').filter(function(){
          return $.trim(($(this).text()) === '(None)'
   }).parents('li').hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mu2uX/5/)

Comment: This example will only hide the `<label>` element, not the `<li>`, resulting in an empty list item. Also, it is more efficient in this case to use `parents()`, rather than `closest()`.

Comment: Finally, your solution doesn't work, because none of the `span.name` elements have a text of `(none)`.